# Methods after dictionary creation are never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

i have a problem with this method:

```
//adding pictures into te core data.
-(void)addPictures
{
    if (self.url) {
        NSDate *data = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:self.creationDate]; //create the right nsdata, ready for be stored in core data
        NSLog(@"test");
        NSDictionary *photo = @{PHOTO_URL: self.url,
                                PHOTO_LATITUDE: (self.latitude) ? self.latitude : [NSNull null],
                                PHOTO_LONGITUDE: (self.longitude) ? self.longitude : [NSNull null],
                                PHOTO_DESCRIPTION: (self.description) ? self.description : [NSNull null],
                                PHOTO_SOCIAL_SITE: self.socialSite,
                                PHOTO_TITLE: self.title,
                                PHOTO_DATE: (data) ? data : [NSNull null],
                                PHOTO_THUMBNAILURL: self.thumbnailURL,
                                PHOTO_THUMBNAIL: self.thumbnail
                                };
        NSLog(@"photo : %@",photo);
        [Photo photoWithInfo:photo inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

i have the problem after the dictionary creation, because the NSlog and the method after are never called. i can't explain why! the instruction up the dictionary creation are execute normally. Maybe there is something wrong during the dictionary creation, but i dont get any error or warning.

Comment: Have you confirmed that none of the values being added to the dictionary are nil?

Comment: Have you confirmed that self.url is not nil or null ?

Comment: @ChrisH you are right, i have one object nil, but why i don't have an error at the execution time?